# req.cookies is [Object: null prototype] {} on express router

Tags: express, cookies, router

Im currently trying to get some cookies for authentication purposes. Im using a backend API and a react Frontend to get the site working. But as soon as I try to get cookies in the backend with express, the only response I get is this: `[Object: null prototype] {}`

The cookies are stored [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKwpl.png), but cant be accessed. Any Idea why this is happening? Here is my code:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const route = Router();

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
route.use(cookieParser());

route.get("/", async (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.cookies)
})
```

Any Idea why it keeps doing this? Thank you for your help :D

---

***Edit***
I just noticed when I use fetch, its returning undefined, if I access the address by hand, its giving me the correct cookie. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cbx3.png)
Im using this code to fetch:

```
fetch(`${config.hosts.INTERNAL_API}/`, { 
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => this.setState(data))
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `credentials: 'include'` to your fetch call, like so:

```
fetch(`${config.hosts.INTERNAL_API}/`, { 
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
}).then(res => res.json()).then(data => this.setState(data))
```

The reason it works when you manually access the address is because HTTP requests made by the browser send cookies in the header by default. Fetch doesn't.