# req.cookies returns [Object: null prototype] {} even if the cookie is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I try to store and read a cookie via cookie-parser. Setting the cookie is working fine. Its listed under the "Application"-Tab of the dev tools:

[image]

But if i try to read the cookie like this:

```js
app.post("/authStatus", function(req,res){

    console.log(req.cookies)
    
})
```

It will give back an empty Object:

[image]

Here is the whole Backend File:

```js
const   cookieParser          = require("cookie-parser"),
        express               = require("express"),
        mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
        bcrypt                = require("bcrypt"),
        Joi                   = require("joi"),
        cors                  = require("cors"),
        jwt                   = require("jsonwebtoken"),
        
        app                   = express()

        require("dotenv").config()
        
        app.use(cookieParser())
        app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
        app.use(cors({
            origin: "http://localhost:3000",
            credentials: true,
        }))

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
},() => {
    console.log("Status: Mongoose: Connected (Test Database)")
})

//Models

const User          = require("./Models/UserModel")

//ValidationFunctions

const {registerValidation, loginValidation} = require("./Validation")
const VerifyToken = require("./VerifyToken")

//Search

app.post("/search", function(req,res,next){
    var keyword = req.body.keyword
    res.redirect("/search/"+ keyword)
})

app.get("/search/:keyword", function(req,res,next){

})

//Registration


app.post("/register", async (req,res) => {

    //Validation

    const {error} = registerValidation(req.body)

    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

    //Check if user is already in Database

    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})

    if(emailExist) return res.status(400).send("")

    // Create User 
    try{
        
        const saltRounds = 10;

        var hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds)

        const user = new User({
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            lastname:req.body.lastname,
            gender:req.body.gender,
            birth:req.body.birth,
            street:req.body.street,
            streetnumber:req.body.streetnumber,
            location: req.body.location,
            email:req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword,

        })

        user.save().then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            res.redirect("/registered")
        })
        
    }
    catch{
        res.status(400).send(err)
    }
})

//Login/Logout

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {

    // Validation

    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body)
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

    // Check if email exist in DB
    
    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send("No user found")
    console.log(user)

    // Password is correct 
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Wrong password")
    
    // Create and assign token
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)

    res.cookie("auth", token, {httpOnly: true, secure:false}).redirect("/main")
})

app.post("/authStatus", function(req,res){

    console.log(req.signedCookies)
    console.log(req.cookies)
    
})

app.post("/logout", (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("auth", 0, {maxAge:0}).redirect("/main")
})

function verifyToken(req,res,next){

    const token = req.cookies

    if(!token) return res.redirect("/loginFirst")

    try{    
        const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)
        req.user = user
    }

    catch{
        res.status(400).send("Invalid Token")
    }
}


app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
    console.log("Status: Express: Server running on PORT: " + process.env.PORT)
})
```

I hope you can help me with that, im quite stuck with it.

Comment: Is your cookieparser above other routes?

Comment: if you mean app.use(cookieParser()) then yes. Its right after the require-consts and the database connection

Comment: Can you share me your app.js or server.js whole code?

Comment: i provided the backend code in the parent post

Comment: Maybe it is cors problem. Is your backend and frontend port same?

Comment: The backend is running on Port 5000 and the frontend on Port 3000. I also thought about a cors issue, but didnt came to a solution

Comment: By the way, i tried to set the cookie on httpOnly:false and i was able to extract his content with document.cookie at the frontend. So the problem does not lie in the cookie itself, but in the connection between front and backend anywhere

Comment: I solved it (see the answers), but thank you very much for the help sir

Answer (score 4):

if it can help anyone, I had the same problem, my error was that I put the cookie-parser middleware at the bottom of the cors middleware. After write it at first next to the app declaration it works as well.

```js
const app = express();

app.use(cookies());

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL ?? "http://localhost:3000",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like i solved the problem, nevertheless I cannot explain exactly why it works now. On the frontend i fired the request via Axios and typed "http://localhost:5000/authStatus" as the URL. I tried to just fire it with just "/authStatus" and added a proxy of "http://localhost:5000" in the frontend package.json. And now it works.

Comment: It was indeed cors error. When you use proxy , you make request to same port in backend and frontend, hence solving cors error

Comment: @Saral Karki how did you solve it?

Comment: @KylianMbappe Are you facing similar error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970252/req-cookies-is-object-null-prototype-on-express-router

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
res.cookie("auth", token, {httpOnly: true, secure:false}).redirect("/main")
})
```

to

```
res.cookie("auth", token, {httpOnly: true}).redirect("/main")
})
```

I am not sure if you are using thunderclient or postman to test apis but "secure" is not working when testing in thunderClient. Even though it works on browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add: `withCredentials: true`, when you send the `req` to the backend

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    try {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/add-book',
            {
                universityOption,
                collegeOption,
                subjectOption,
                emailOption,
                phoneNumberOption,
                file,
                postAs
            },
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                setUniversityOption('')
                setCollegeOption('')
                setSubjectOption('')
                setEmailOption('')
                setPhoneNumbeOption('')
                setFile('')
                setPostAs([])
            })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me.. adding `credentials: "include"` with the fetch request solved the problem.

**Problem:**

```js
fetch("domain", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    //headers
  },
}).then(//...)
```

This gave `[Object: null prototype] {}` when fetching cookies at the backend.

**Solution:**

Adding credentials: "include" solved the problem for me.

```js
fetch("domain", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    //headers
  },
  credentials: "include",
}).then(//...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set all the other cookie-related settings in both the frontend and backend correctly but still you get this error, it is because you might be using "127.0.0.1". So instead of using "127.0.0.1", use "localhost:port", like this "http://localhost:5000".

Please note you have to set all other settings correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your backend code looks good to me.

Remember in order to persist the cookie on the front-end you have to have pass

```
{ withCredentials: true }
```

On axios request from front-end

Or

```
credentials: 'include'
```

If you are using fetch method

Backend:

In your backend code, you must define the possible origin or conditional origin, for example.

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        ? process.env.CLIENT_URL
        : "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);
```

Frontend:

```
await axios.post(url, { body },{ withCredentials: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **axios** to request:-

```
const res = axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem: `req.cookies` - `[Object: null prototype] {}`.
`Set-Cookies` works well on the server side:

`res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', getRefreshTokenHttpOnlySetCookie(refreshToken, AUTH_REFRESH_INTERVAL))` adds cookie

[image]

My React App uses **urql** to make request via Hasura Actions.

```
const createUrqlClient = (headers: StringRecord = defaultHeaders) => createClient({
  url: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
  fetchOptions: {
    headers,
    credentials: 'include'
  },
  exchanges: [
    ...defaultExchanges,
    subscriptionExchange({
      forwardSubscription: (operation) => ({
        subscribe: (sink) => ({
          unsubscribe: getWsClient(headers).subscribe(operation, sink)
        })
      })
    })
  ]
});
```

Server works on NestJS app, **main.ts** contains:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import { AppModule } from './app.module'
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './utils/exceptions/http-exception.filter'
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import * as cors from 'cors'

const PORT = process.env.HASURA_ACTIONS_PORT ?? 3003

global['fetch'] = require('node-fetch')

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter())
  app.enableCors()
  app.use(cookieParser())
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      credentials: true
    })
  )
  await app.listen(PORT)
}
bootstrap()
```

When performing any request there is no any cookies :(
`[Object: null prototype] {}`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem: req.cookies - [Object: null prototype] {}. Set-Cookies works well on the server side

i use this
axios
.get(`${server}/getuser`, {
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
withCredentials: true,
})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding credentials: 'include' to your fetch call, like so:

```
fetch(`${process.env.SERVER_URL}/`, { 
     method: "POST",
     credentials: "include",
     headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },})
    .then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))
```

The reason it works when you manually access the address is because HTTP requests made by the browser send cookies in the header by default. Fetch doesn't.